# Does jQuery .ready() function hosting all the function expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is Pseudo-code of jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   printHelloworld(); 
});    
var printHelloworld = function(){
   console.log('hello world');
}
```

In this sample, the console will print hello world.

My question is that Function expression must be assigned before usage, but  in this sample, I used the printHelloworld() before assigned it. I do not know what have .ready() function done? Did it do something to hoist the function?

Comment: As the name suggests the document ready function will run when the document is ready. By that time it has access to printHelloworld  as this is declared globally. Please check https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: this function is delcared after but it work cause ready function only work after all document is loaded

Answer (score 0):

The `var` hoisted the `printHelloworld` function declaration to the top of the function (or script). It wasn't initialized until you assigned it after your `$(document).ready()` statement, but the anonymous function you passed to `ready` still held a reference to the variable. By the time the function executed, the `printHelloworld` variable was initialized and usable.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

> Because variable declarations (and declarations in general) are processed before any code is executed, declaring a variable anywhere in the code is equivalent to declaring it at the top. This also means that a variable can appear to be used before it's declared.